# Adding two numbers with a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA code to add two numbers:

```
Option Explicit

Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Function addtwo(x, y)
addtwo = x + y    
End Function
```

This is not a good function since I have to manually input the values x and y to get for the result. How can I modify the codes so it can work with any two numbers, no matter integers or numbers with decimals?

Comment: Is the solution offered going to work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You define your input variables in the FUNCTION declaration line, not above it.  I would recommend the vartype DOUBLE for whole numbers and decimals.

```
Function ADDTWO(ByVal x As Double,ByVal  y As Double) As Double
    ADDTWO = x + y
End Function
```

Now this function can be used in a cell as:

**=ADDTWO(3, 6)**
or
**=ADDTWO(A2, B7)**

It can also be used in VBA.

Of course, the SUM() function does this same thing, so....I presume this is a learning exercise.

Comment: + 1 :) Yes ideally this is a nice way to do it. however it has it's own disadvantages :(

Comment: @Siddharth - I'm always up to learn... what disadvantages does Double introduce?

Comment: I will have to post an answer for that as this comment box will not be sufficient for it. Would that be okay with you and Rob? :)

Comment: `what disadvantages does Double introduce` My post is ready but I decided posting against it. Let me try and put it here in minimal words. `Double` or any other DataType (except variant) in your function doesn't have any disadvantages. It's the way it is used in the function which can restrict it's "Use" and hence creates a disadvantage I was referring to. If you change your first line to `Function ADDTWO(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double) As Double` then that should take care of the disadvantage. ;)

Comment: Of course, @Siddharth, post an answer!  Mine are always too short to really help anyway... more like inspiration for the next question.  Hmm.  So the `ByVal` is the enhancement you're suggesting.  To be honest I never use that keyword - can you clue me in a bit as to its helpfulness here?

Comment: No that is ok :) Just change it to what I suggested :)

Comment: I've edited this code above with Siddharth's excellent suggestion.  Did some reading up on the ByRef and ByVal parameters and I get how it helps to clarify that the "value" from the reference cells should be used.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 I avoided rating this earlier because of the use of ByRef. ByVal is the way to go in almost all cases unless you have a special reason to use ByRef. This is not just because your variable is safe from edits, but also because it fits in perfectly with the OOP concept.

Answer (score 2):

As far as working with any two numbers, try the `Variant` data type instead of `Integer`.  Not sure what you mean by manually inputting the values - are you talking about getting them from the worksheet?

Comment: + 1 I am not in favor of variants but in this case variants is the way to go. :)